# How can I make electricity with magnets

Tags: inductor, electromagnetic

Please keep in mind that this is a new concept I am learn so I do apologize

Using electromagnetic induction How can I make electricity with magnets? And how can I produce a powerful supply of that electricity?

Comment: Just sticking a magnet next to a coil of wire will do nothing at all. You're entire question is lacking any detail or information needed to give any form of useful answer. "a magnet" - there are many different types and strengths. "about 4 inches" - so are some pieces of string, what of it?. "wrapped it 150-200 times" - wrapped around what? what wire? diameter? length? "how much electricity could I get out" - somewhere between 0 and infinity.

Comment: Pardon moi? Could you please clarify your application and your goals. Your question is vague in many areas.

Comment: "EMI" is Electromagnetic Interference, as when a microwave oven screws up your wifi links.  If you meant something else than interference, don't say "EMI," instead spell out the entire name.

Comment: Sorry. I meant a electromagnetic induction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most electricity is made with magnets and coils. But you must MOVE either the coils and/or the magnets to produce electricity.

Recommend studying some of the fundamentals of the physics involved.  For example:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_generator

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternator

Comment: Thanks for helping and also guiding me to learn more. Most people here just see you don't know what your talking about and criticize instead of helping

Comment: @LostPecti Most people around here expect you to do some basic research for yourself before posting.

Comment: I do, but these are concept you will just get. As shown above you will think you understand something but will turn out your wrong and misread.. This is the problem in learning on your own.

Comment: Concept you WON'T just get....

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on your actual goal.   Do you want to cheaply power an appliance such as a computer, room light, etc.?    Or, do you just want to experiment, build your own DIY devices, learn about magnets, etc.?

If you just want to power something, then a bicycle-powered electric generator is one way to go.  Human legs can put out about 100 watts, or less in long term, or more if trained (such as daily biking uphill.)   If you want to build your own setup, simply buy a used treadmill motor off sites such as eBay, and use it as a generator (being driven by a roller and human legs pumping the bike pedals.)  Be sure to buy a "DCPM" treadmill motor; one that contains permanent magnets and has a DC output.  THey're often available for as low as $50.  Search on: treadmill motor wind turbine.  (Yes, old treadmill motors are widely used as simple DIY wind-power generators.)   Hint: a 90V DCPM motor will generate ninety volts when being spun at its rated motor-RPM.   If you want only 24volts, then spin it slower, at roughly 1/4 of the spec RPM of your motor.

Or, do you want to build a DIY generator from scratch?   This is much more difficult than simply buying a used treadmill motor.   The typical method is to wind heavy pancake coils of copper wire, embed them in solid epoxy, then pass them near a large expensive magnet (a neo rare-earth magnet, like a hockey puck.)   As with the bike generator, if you want to produce 100 watts output, you'll have to perform at least 100 watts of muscle work in spinning the magnets or the coils.  One DIY site for these types of generator is "otherpower.com," the wind-power site for self-built generators.  Here's one of their typical projects: a 6,000watt low-RPM generator for a wind-turbine tower with blades 10ft long.

[Wind turbine project: Six kilowatt DIY generator](http://www.otherpower.com/20page1.html)

[Smaller version: hamster-powered night light](http://www.otherpower.com/hamster.html)

On the other hand, if you want to mess around with coils and magnets, here is my links-page to all sorts of small "Science Fair" sized DIY generators.

[Tiny DIY generators: links collection](http://amasci.com/coilgen/generator_4.html)

Finally: is your goal to produce high wattage without having to pump a bicycle pedals?  These are the DIY water turbine projects.  But you need some private land with a waterfall or fast-flowing stream.  Or, there's the 20ft wind-turbine linked above.  Or, attach a lawnmower gasoline engine to your DIY generator.

Finally: beware of "Free Energy Device" websites, whose owners will insist that they can run their appliances without doing any work, by using secret magnet-coil devices suppressed by the government.  They won't give any proof though, and you can easily waste decades in pursuit of perpetual motion machines, when everyone else is successfully powering their mountain cabins using wind turbines and solar panels.  And bike-generators, to recharge their phones and tablet batteries.